# How to use a float as an env var in cargo/rust?

Tags: rust, environment-variables, rust-cargo

Like the title suggests, how can I create an env variable in cargo that is of type float?

I have a created .cargo/config.toml file and would like to add all the game related env variables like so:

```
[env]
test = "testtingggg"
yo = "yoyoyoyoyoyo"
game_zero_level = "hello"
game_zero_multiplier = 0.1
# game_one_level = 1
# game_one_multiplier = 1.0
# game_two_level = 2
# game_two_multiplier = 2.5
# game_three_level = 3
# game_three_multiplier = 5.0
# game_four_level = 3
```

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub level_zero: LevelZero,
    pub level_one: LevelOne,
    pub level_two: LevelTwo,
    pub level_three: LevelThree,
    pub level_four: LevelFour,

}
impl Config {
    pub fn new() -> Self {

        // Get env variables
        let temp = option_env!("game_zero_level").unwrap();
        msg!("simple env read for first game...");
        msg!("{}", temp);

        // load them into struct
        // template for now
        Config {
            level_zero: LevelZero { level: 0, multiplier: 1.0 },
            level_one: LevelOne { level: 1, multiplier: 1.0 },
            level_two: LevelTwo { level: 2, multiplier: 1.0 },
            level_three: LevelThree { level: 3, multiplier: 1.0 },
            level_four: LevelFour { level: 4, multiplier: 1.0 },
        }
    }
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU2Tc.png)

However, I got an error:

```
2022-12-24T18:22:59.802122509Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain packag
e metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: could not load Cargo
 configuration
    
    Caused by:
      failed to load TOML configuration from `/home/tai/Code/solana/techniques
/env-vars3/programs/env-vars3/.cargo/config.toml`
    
    Caused by:
      failed to parse key `env`
    
    Caused by:
      failed to parse key `game_zero_multiplier`
    
    Caused by:
      found TOML configuration value of unknown type `float`
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5TZN.png)

Any suggestions would be soo appreciated! Thanks

Comment: roger, edited sir*

Comment: Environment variables generally must be text — I think this is due to strings being the only format understood by the various C subprocess functions like `execv`. Your best bet is probably to enter it as a string and parse to a float. Or store these values either in source.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response! I think Im misunderstanding, but what do you mean by source? Like a source file with .rs extension and hardcode them?

Comment: yep, that's what I meant. (Remove “either” from my response)